# Read javascript code in selenium without opening browser

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working with selenium API to webcrapping on pages with javascript.

Is there some method to get the code without a web browser screen opens ?

I am new to this API

Is possible?

Answer (score 8):

You have, at least, 3 basic options:

- use a **headless browser**, like [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/), example:

  ```
  >>> from selenium import webdriver
  >>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
  >>> driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
  >>> driver.title
  u'Stack Overflow'
  ```
- use a **virtual display** (see [`xvfb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)) with the help of [`pyvirtualdisplay`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay), examples here:

  - [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)
  - [Selenium with pyvirtualdisplay unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485360/selenium-with-pyvirtualdisplay-unable-to-locate-element)
- use a **remote selenium server**, either your own with setting up own nodes in a grid, or at, for example, [`BrowserStack`](http://www.browserstack.com/), or [`Sauce Labs`](https://saucelabs.com/):

  ```
  >>> from selenium import webdriver
  >>> from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
  >>> 
  >>> desired_cap = {'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': 'xp', 'browser': 'IE', 'browser_version': '7.0' }
  >>> driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://username:key@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
  >>> 
  >>> driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
  >>> driver.title
  u'Stack Overflow'
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't use JavaScript without an interpreter, which is in a browser. Though, you may use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) - a headless browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could use headless browser.
For example
http://phantomjs.org/ or http://slimerjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

"Is there some method to get the code without a web browser screen opens?"- **YES**! 
You have to import `Options`.

```
from selenium import webdriver   # for webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
```

Then in the code:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

And continue with the rest of the program.