# Using Python+Selenium to click on a link on Yahoo Finance

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to click on a link from this page using selenium webdriver in Python 3:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1'
display = Display(visible=0,size=(600,800))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Statistics')
```

The above code doesn't work using the two lines with display and throws an error about not being able to click the element. But it does work if I comment them out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485360/selenium-with-pyvirtualdisplay-unable-to-locate-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out why it doesn't work. The display size (600,800) was too small. Once I set the size to the maximum allowed by my monitor the element was then found.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your URL is not wrapped in quotes.  I'd bet that is your problem.

Change

```
url = https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1
```

to

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1"
```

Comment: actually that was a typo on my part. I've since corrected it.