# Extract cookies from open Safari session in Python

Tags: python, http, cookies, web, urllib2

Trying to follow the example in this one:

[Python urllib2 login to minecraft.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427996/python-urllib2-login-to-minecraft-net)

I'm trying to get files from this website and it's a tedious process of clicking to get to each file.  I could easily use urllib2 to webscrape but, of course, you have to be logged in to this website to get the data.  I tried doing one of the login type approaches in Python but I can't get it to work.

My other option is to export the cookies from Safari session so I can run my webscraping scripts to get the data I need.

**Does anyone know how to export cookies from Safari session to Python for access to website data?**

Comment: Use https://www.getpostman.com/ to see cookies and all the calls you make, but you need Chrome to use it

Comment: Also why not use requests Session object to have a cookie jar and use their HTTPAuth methods as well??

Comment: @heinst hey thanks! can you link me to an example of a way to use requests session objects?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: Whats the url for the site where you want to download the files from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to login and download a file, this uses BeautifulSoup and Requests:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
    return local_filename

s = requests.Session()

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://minecraft.net/login").content)

authToken = soup.find('form', attrs={'id': 'loginForm'}).findNext('input')['value']

data = {
    "username": "USERNAME",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "remember": "true",
    "authenticityToken": authToken
}

s.post("https://minecraft.net/login", data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://minecraft.net//download").content)
download_file(soup.find("div", attrs={'id': 'platform-osx'}).findNext('p').findNext('')['href'])
```